# Are container.end() and container.size() inlined?

Tags: c++, performance, containers, inline

I typically get into the discussion with others and I'm not able to confirm the behavior - if the container.end() and container.size() functions are inlined. For e.g. if we have a for loop as such:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it) {
   //...
} 

for (size_t k=0; k < v.size(); ++k) {
   //...
}
```

In the above cases, will the v.end() and v.size() functions be called repeatedly or

1. will compiler inline these functions
2. Will temporary variable be created by compiler
3. Does optimization options O1..3 impact the behavior in g++?

Comment: The answer will depend, in part, upon the specific container you are using.

Comment: Also which implementation of that container and quite possibly which version of gcc you're using and for which platform.

Comment: Normally, if you are getting an object such as an iterator and not modifying it, the compiler will cache it in a temporary variable. I could also see it inlining those methods since they are trivial (for a vector). However, as others have also mentioned, specific optimizations vary by compiler as well as which settings you are using.

Comment: I'm using g++ on linux with -03 optimization. Is there a way to check what is happening with my settings? When i step through code with gdb, If I do a step into at the for loop line, will it help.  For stl containers with clearly defined end() and size() why will the behavior be different?

Comment: Stepping through the code in gdb is pretty much guaranteed to confuse you even more than you already are.  If you *must* know the answer -- keep in mind that there's a  strong case that you shouldn't ask this question -- the only way to find out for sure is to add `-save-temps` to your compile command, then read through the assembly dump.

Comment: Also, many versions of GCC produce *slower* code at `-O3` than `-O2` or even `-Os`.  Have you actually benchmarked it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All template functions are by definition inline functions. The compiler may choose to make them callable functions, especially if it's a debug mode compilation, but the most likely outcome is for the code to be inlined.

It's possible but unlikely that a temporary variable will be automatically created. How does the compiler determine if the v.end() or v.size() return values will be impacted by the code within the loop? I suspect most don't bother, although I don't have any evidence either way.

Comment: Template functions do not have to be inline and certainly aren't required to be inline by definition. It's just that it assists instantiation (which is obviously important). They can be defined separately to their declaration, and potentially need to be explicitly instantiated.

Comment: The compiler will definately bother. The question is, if it can tell for certain, that the return value of size()/end() cannot change. If it can "see" the code of all functions called within the loop, it often can. In those cases, many compilers will fetch/compute the result of size()/end() only once, and reuse it for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: GCC considers template member functions defined outside of the class body to _not_ be inline.  This can be demonstrated with the `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` flag.  Inline definitions (whether template or not) will be treated as hidden.  Out-of-line template definitions will only be treated as hidden if they are explicitly marked as `inline`.

Comment: Function templates are subject to the exact same rules for being inlined as non-template ones. A function defined inside the class definition is considered inline, a function declared with the `inline` keyword is considered inline, and other function definitions are not. So if you define a function template outside the class, without using the `inline` keyword, the function template won't be inline.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the functions are inlined, you cannot count on the compiler to correctly optimize the loop if the nested code is sufficiently large/complex.  This is because *semantically*, you probably don't expect the `end()` value to change on every iteration of the loop, so it should only be computed once and.  However, the compiler may not be able to make that guarantee based on aliasing considerations and other "give-up" conditions in the optimizer.  If--like other posters have answered--you pre-calculate `end()` and store it in a variable, the compiler is less likely to get confused.

For example:

```
typedef std::vector<int> intvec;
intvec v = external_function();
for (intvec::const_iterator vi = v.begin(); vi != v.end(); ++vi) {
    call_external_function(v, *vi);
}
```

From the compiler's perspective, `call_external_function()` is liable to change the size of the vector.  If you know it cannot happen, you should be *telling* the compiler so:

```
for (intvec::const_iterator vi = v.begin(), ve = v.end(); vi != ve; ++vi) {
    call_external_function(v, *vi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though template functions are inlined, it's difficult to say that compiler will provide the same degree of optimization we need.
One can use below techniques.

Store `v.end()` in a temporary `vEnd`:

```
for(vector<TYPE>::iterator it = v.begin(), vEnd = v.end(); it != vEnd; it++) {}
```

Execute the loop in reverse:

```
for (size_t k = v.size() - 1; k != (size_t)(-1) ; --k) { }
```

Comment: reverse `for` loop + unsigned loop variable + `>= 0` = disaster

Comment: @pgroke, why is it disaster ? I am interested to know.

Comment: because, `k` being unsigned, `k >= 0` will **always** be true. so the loop will run forever. when `k` reaches zero, it will be decremented again, which will cause an underflow. the underflow will produce the highest number that `k` can hold (i.e. `0xffffffff` if `k` is 32 bits wide).

Comment: That's still not correct, since `k` is still unsigned and will still underflow. After the underflow, converting it to a `long int` will either give you a positive number (if `long int` is wide enough to hold the max. value of `size_t`) or undefined behavior (if `long int` is not wide enough). The best (easy) solution that I know is to change the type of `k` to `ptrdiff_t` (which is signed, and should be wide enough to hold any that value `vector::size()` might ever return). i.e. `for (ptrdiff_t k = v.size() - 1; k >= 0 ; --k) { }`

Comment: @pgroke: Or use `k != (size_t)-1`.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: heh, you're right, never thought of that! Now that I was thinking in terms of guaranteed unsigned arithmetics and layout, I had another idea (a very nasty one): use `~k` for the condition. That would surely confuse the hell out of everyone who reads it :)

Comment: @Charles Bailey, should that be equivalent to the current edit ? i.e `k != (size_t)(-1);`

Comment: @iammilind: Yes, the extra parentheses in your version are redundant. They don't change the meaning, and both are equivalent to `k != static_cast<size_t>(-1)`

Comment: @iammilind: You could avoid the reverse loop silliness and do the same thing you did with the iterator: `for (size_t k = 0, kEnd = v.size(); k != kEnd; ++k) { }`